# random background image in UITableviewCell

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, uitableview

I would like to know if how can i build a dynamic UItable with random background image? e.g i have 6 images called back1.png, back2.png, back3.png......back6.png.

What code to be added in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

I only can sequentially assign each cells with a specific image as follow,

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightwood1.jpg"]];
}
if(indexPath.row == 1){
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightwood2.jpg"]];
}
if(indexPath.row == 2){
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightwood3.jpg"]];
}
```

But how I can just change it to randomly with unlimited rows in a UITableView?

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lightwood%d",arc4random()%6]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
int lowerBound = 1;
int upperBound = 7;
int randomValue = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);

newView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lightwood%d.jpg", randomValue]]];
```

Comment: Error message shown:too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2. What does it mean and how to solve? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This one, May be help full

```
newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lightwood%d.jpg", indexPath.row]]];
```

indexPath.row increase one by one and your images name also increasing one by one.... 
Thanks

Comment: it'll not work in this case because there are only 6 images and when `indexPath.row` will return grater than 6 then your code will fall to load the image.

Comment: I have other way you need manage this using If else condition

Comment: how do you managed random function using if else condition? can you please elaborate??

Comment: see I gave another answer hope this work fine... Thanks